# Weird character in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am getting weird character in emacs when I open certain code. It is like ^M. I think it's something related to character encoding, or maybe not. Can something help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: This would possibly be better on SuperUser. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/what-site-should-host-questions-about-emacs-keybinding for a vaguely related discussion. As there does not appear to be a consensus, I am not voting to move it right now.

Answer (score 7):

that's a carriage return (CR) char (because the file probably has windows line endings: CRLF).

you can get rid of those line endings in emacs

```
M-x replace-string RET C-q C-M RET RET
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: my previous information was not quite right
If you want to set windows encoding on save, [C-x <return> f dos <return>](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html) will set the file to save in dos encoding, so Windows users can read it properly. Similarly you can do C-x <return> f unix <return> to cause the file to change to unix formatting on save.

`C-x <return> r dos yes` will switch over to dos mode in the current buffer (fixing line endings, and preserving formatting of the file), and is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file, and see the encoding is not right (i.e. has ^M characters everywhere, or unicode trash for instance), I find it easiest to `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system RET dos RET` (replace dos with utf-16 or whatever you need).

This way you can open up the file in its preferred coding system.  If you need to change the coding system, you can then do `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (`C-x RET f`) to switch it out to unix.